# Scene 2D fps drop need to resize atlases maybe there is a better solution?

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl-es, libgdx, cocos2d-android, scene2d

I'm in the final stages of deploying my game. It all works well , no lags, I have constant 60 FPS on all devices over 480 x 800 resolution that are maybe a Samsung or something similar in brand.

However on devices as small as 240 x 320 or on Chinese phones with bad OSs the screens with my dynamic Scene2D elements (there are lots of stacks, tables, actors, etc) make the loading of the five 1024x1024 atlases kind of hard and the rendering kind of laggy.

I'm going to make 3 sets of atlases big , medium, smaller. However that is going to rise my APK size from 35MB to over 50MB, at least.

Is there any better solution than atlas resize which can be deployed with no major code restructuring (a day, or two max) ?

Also, which is better on older low res. phones?

**1.** 2 x 1024x1024 texture atlas PNGs

**or**

**2.** 8 x 512x512 texture atlas PNGs

Multiple PNGs means more texture changes per render , correct? But which is better : smaller PNGs or lesser PNGs if we were to pick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low Size textures are better for older/smaller devices for better performance. however you can choose [Quality Settings for different devices based on Specs](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/843326/unity-46-android-changing-quality-level-during-run.html)

Thumb Up if its helpful